# Open a bug on release fails in VSTS Continuous Deployment

Tags: azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have configured and scheduled only release definition on VSTS for Azure solution deployment which is having PowerShell tasks. But I want to open a bug or work item in VSTS if release/ deployment fails.

Is it possible in VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible for VSTS to create a bug if a release failed.

Add another **PowerShell task** in the end of your release definition to create a bug if the previous task fails. Detail settings for the PowerShell task as below:

Select **Only when a previous task has failed** for Rume this task option, so if the previous task failed, this PowerShell task will be executed.

[image]

The add the powershell script to [create a bug work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) like:

```
$witType="Bug"
$witTitle="title"
$u="https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_apis/wit/workitems/`$$($witType)?api-version=1.0"
$body="[
  {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/fields/System.Title`",
    `"value`": `"$($witTitle)`"
  }
]"
$user = "username"
$token = "PAT"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri $u -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```

Comment: I don't want to add any script or file to the repository because this repo is used for production. Owner/Stakeholders won't allows me to add a file to the product code.   Is there any other way by external tools or task?
  But this is a good approach, Let me try for next project

Comment: What's the agent you used for the deployment, Hosted or private agent? If you  are using private agent, it's unnecessary to change your repo. And unfortunately, there is no such settings to auto create bug when deployment failed.

Comment: That's a good idea... I can set up the private agent and upload the script to the agent VM.

Comment: Yeah, for private agent, you can specify the `.ps1` on the agent machine ( such as the path `C:\root\1.ps1` in the example https://imgur.com/a/QJfzF).

Comment: One more question Marina Liu. Where will I get the log of error from release? I am using PowerShell tasks in the release and I want to attach release error log to the bug opened by release.

Comment: You can open the page for a release -> Logs Tab -> double click a task to check the detail log, as https://imgur.com/a/ETKeO.

Comment: Yes right, But I want to attach this log to the system info field of bug when release create the bug automatically on release failure

Comment: For system info field, you can add info about software or system info. Do you mean attach the release log in system info field? If you want to attach the release log, you'd better add in other field.

Comment: @ Marina Liu or Any one can tell me when we say " Only when a previous task has failed" means all the previous task in the pipeline or just one immediate task (the above one)