# How to create bug or Notification in only one task/Job when other task/Job failed in an Agent in devops in Release Pipe line

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have an pipeline which will have few task mentioned in the image. I'm creating a bug work item when a particular task failed which is working fine using logic app.

Now my problem is I don't want to add every time new task for bug creation after each deployment task mentioned in the image.

Is there any way I can create only one bug work item based on failure in any of the task in the pipeline. may be in the last or somewhere..?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you had to go the Logic app route as there is an option to do this with Azure Pipelines itself out of the box.

Navigate to `{your pipeline} > Options` as shown below:

[image: Create work item on failure]

If the build pipeline fails, you can automatically create a work item to track getting the problem fixed. You can specify the work item type. You can also select if you want to assign the work item to the requestor. For example, if this is a CI build, and a team member checks in some code that breaks the build, then the work item is assigned to that person.

Additional Fields: You can also set the value of other work item fields. For example:

```
Field           Value
-------         -------
System.Title    Build $(Build.BuildNumber) failed
System.Reason   Build failure
```

Check [Build Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops) for more details.

**UPDATE:**

Doing this for Release Pipelines is not supported as an out of the box feature as of today. However, there are extensions available in the Visual Studio marketplace that can be used as alternatives until it is supported.

Here are two such extensions:

- [Create Bug on Release failure](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmanBedi18.CreateBugTask)
- [Create Work Item](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.CreateWorkItem)

Another idea with PowerShell tasks is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48200177/10805761).

Comment: Thanks for you response but this option is only available in build pipeline not in release pipeline. I'm looking for Release pipeline jobs when there is a failure bug will create so i used logic app.

Comment: @GauravJoshi Oh ok. Edited my answer with more details. Please check.

Comment: @GauravJoshi If your requirements are still not met with the above options, please create a new idea on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) so the Azure DevOps Team can take a look.

Comment: @GauravJoshi Does that help?

Comment: : thanks for your updated answer though I can't use extensions to create bug. also I don't want to use PowerShell task for this purpose because i have to call Kusto query for fetching errors.